# Flutter - How to create variable colors in BoxDecoration

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm creating a table where the values ​​are placed according to a list, but I want the color of each cell in the table to be varied between two different colors, I would like to know if there is any way to do this, using BoxDecoration as shown below

[image]

```
 String color = "0xFFE8CFA7";
 Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 6, vertical: 6),
          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
            color: Color(color),
          ),
          child: Column(
              children: previsao
                  .map((e) => Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            width: 104,
                            child: Text("${e.diaSemana}",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 16,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),
                          ),
                          Text("T", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
                          Text("${e.tempMin}°",
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
                          Text("${e.tempMax}°",
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
                        ],
                      ))
                  .toList())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, declare an int variable like this:

```
int index = 0;
```

Then in the `color` property of the widget which you have multiples of it, you can set it like this:

```
color: (index++) % 2 == 0 ? Colors.red : Colors.blue,
```

This will result in a different colors for each widget like this:

[image]

Comment: did this helps you achieving what you want ?